# Is forging internal documents at work a crime?

Tags: legal, documentation

I currently work in a semi truck repair facility. Where we regularly do services and federal inspections on trucks for the Department of transportation. We have an internal computer program that logs Times, completions, and comments on jobs done, essentially a digital work order. I have worked on trucks without finishing, and later went back to complete the jobs on the list and found my name was entered under the federal inspection line and it was marked complete even though I haven’t gotten that far yet, and the truck does not pass inspection. 
I’m wondering if this is at all a crime being that it’s an internal system, or if I should be speaking to a lawyer due to it being for a federal inspection.

Comment: I know this question is at the intersection (pun intended) of workplace and law, but you are probably likely to get better answers in law.stackexchange.com

Comment: Does this program record the user who was logged in when the work order log entries are made/updated? If it's being used for tasks that have to be reported to the US DOT, I would expect there to be an audit trail showing the name of the person who isn't you "signing" your name to these inspection jobs. And this is why you need to keep your account secured, with your password known only to you, and you log out or lock the workstation whenever you leave it.

Comment: Alroc- it does log the employees who clock onto it, and the amount of time they spent on it. They are also required to leave comments on each workorder line. The labor time can be edited by management if there are any errors. The way I discovered this was when I saw that my name was on the line but I didn’t remember doing it. So what I did was looked at the information of the labor (typically tells you the time and date you logged on to it) and it said it was a manual entry.

Comment: If your employer gets sued for some reason, and a Court asks for these documents, and the company hands over forged documents, then a crime has happened. I _think_ the company would be responsible in the end. You _ might_ have personal responsibility as well.

Answer (score 12):

There is almost certainly no general crime against forging non-legal documents. (I think the legal definition of forgery specifies legal documents). But there are things to keep in mind:

**Fraud is a crime, and forging documents can be used to commit fraud**

**Just because it is an internal document, doesn't mean it is not a legal document**

The company may be legally obliged to provide internal documentation if they are audited for instance, or may be required to retain documentation under law.

**Internal documentation can be evidence in criminal trials**

Should the police get involved because of a serious incident that occurs because of a defective truck, they will pull records relating to the truck maintenance, and you will firmly be in the crosshairs.

**Even if there is some situation where you are absolved of criminal behaviour, that doesn't prevent the company suing you**

Imagine if the truck goes out, gets involved in an accident due to something you "signed off on". The company can then go and sue you, because you "signed off on" it.

My advice, especially on matters concerning safety, and potential legal liability, is to ensure that no modification is made to things you have signed off on.

I hate recommending speaking to a lawyer, cause it is a bit of a hassle, but I think at this point, you do need to talk to a lawyer to see what your next steps are.

Comment: The issue is to do with alterations on documents that the OP has **not** signed off - not those that have been completed...

Comment: @SolarMike I'm assuming the OP has logged into a system, entered some work with their credentials, and then somebody else has come along and changed that data, making it appear that OP has entered that data. That's what I mean by signed-off.

Comment: @SolarMike The issue is that the alterations on the documents that the OP did not sign off , say the work *has* been completed by the OP.

Comment: @morbo think that was what I was pointing out...

Comment: Would there be value to OP in keeping their own written log (on paper, in ink) of the work they perform, which cannot be altered by management?

Comment: Before looking for a lawyer, a union rep would also be a good resource if the OP is a part of one.